# Rails: succinctly print variable name and <br /> tag if exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My code

```
<%= @invite.host.name %><br />
<%= @invite.host.title %><br />
```

If the name or title aren't present, I don't want to render the `<br />`.

I tried

```
<%= "#{@invite.host.name} <br />" || '' %>
```

But that wasn't working.

I'd rather not do an `if` block. Is there a succinct single line way of achieving what I'm trying to do?

Comment: _"But that wasn't working"_ - what do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a helper method in `ApplicationHelper`:

```
def with_break(content)
  return nil unless content
  (content + content_tag(:br)).html_safe
end
```

and in view, do:

```
<%= with_break @invite.host.name %>
<%= with_break @invite.host.title %>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because string you providing will never be `nil`. If you need one liner, you can do something like this (`.html_safe` is needed to render html tags):

```
<%= "#{@invite.host.name} <br>".html_safe if @invite.host.name.present? %>
```

Or if you need something simpler, you could replace `<br>` tags with `<div>`, which would give same effect:

```
<div><%= @invite.host.name %></div>
<div><%= @invite.host.title %></div>
```